# how to fetch the single name property from nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, lodash, arrayobject

I am working on Angular Project, where i need to fetch name property from given nested array object.
I tried with lodash map function `_.map('ArrayName',(o)=>o.name);` here i am receving only `[ Peter, Andy ]` as result. I want all name property `[Peter, Andy, Mills, mac, Teddy]`like this. Can someone guide me how to do this.

```
[{
"id": "1",
"name": "Peter",
"children": []}
,{
"id": "2",
"name": "Andy",
"children": [
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Mills",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Mac",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Teddy",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to access the nested `children` arrays recursively.

Here is an example using [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to recursively iterate each array of children and flatten the results.

```js
const input = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Peter", "children": [] }, { "id": "2", "name": "Andy", "children": [{ "id": "3", "name": "Mills", "children": [] }, { "id": "4", "name": "Mac", "children": [{ "id": "5", "name": "Teddy", "children": [] }] }] }];

const recursivelyGetProp = (arr, prop) => (
  arr.flatMap(({ children, [prop]: p }) =>
    [p, ...(children.length ? recursivelyGetProp(children, prop) : [])]
  ));

console.log(recursivelyGetProp(input, 'name'));
```